# SCNNode.removeFromParentNode() and rendering loop

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode

i have a question regarding removing SCNNodes
I have a function that makes a SCNNodes, when the Node is ready I add it with:

```
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

then I make a new SCNNode with the function and like to remove the old one and add the new one, unfortunately `SCNNode.removeFromParentNode()` wont remove the old one:

```
func cleanUpAndAdd(){
        for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes{
            if node.name == "object" {
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
                object.name = "object"
            } else {
                scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
                object.name = "object"
            }               
        }            
    }
```

It just adds and adds and never removes...

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you set your SCNViews playing property to true?

    sceneView.isPlaying = true

Otherwise it might look like the object is not remove because the view did not redraw after you remove it.

Comment: I added `scnView.stop(nil)` and `scnView.play(nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. After hours of troubleshooting I realised that the SCNGeometry I was making contained also the SCNGeometry sources from the previous SCNGeometry.

So the rendering and removing was correct.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `SCNNode.childNodes` is a collection (array) and so per Cocoa conventions you should not try to mutate it (`SCNNode.addChildNode(_:)`) while it's being enumerated. If you do so SceneKit will note generate a runtime exception, but the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I removed this part, thank you. I just do the cleanup and add it later.

Comment: If by cleanup you mean `removeFromParentNode`, you shouldn't do that either because it is also mutating the collection.

Answer (score 0):

That code is correct, assuming you have set the node name. You didn't show us that part. How about adding "else print node.name"?

Comment: For clarification I am calling a function with NSNotificationCenter where I  create my object and add it to the scene. When the "Notification" function gets called again I create a new object then I make the clean up and add the new one. I think I have to somehow trigger the Rendering Loop each time I make a new object...